# How can I put the groups in an extra column in a `gt` table?

Tags: r, gt

In the table below, how can I but the groups in an additional column on the left (without duplicating the "A" and "B"), so that the table only has 4 rows instead of 6?

```r
library(gt)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

test <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  year = c(1, 2, 1, 2),
  value = c(8:11)
)

test |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  gt()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  gt() |>
  tab_options(row_group.as_column = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Aurèle's solution.

Without grouping, we can sort by group column then set duplicated rows to blank - `""`.

```
test |> 
  arrange(group, year) |> 
  mutate(group = ifelse(duplicated(group), "", group)) |> 
  gt()
```

[image]